# can't receive push notification in windows 10 universal app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying to migrate windows 8.1 store app project to windows 10 universal app project.
However the win10 app can't receive any push notification while the win8.1 app works fine.
The only difference between two project is the package.appxmanifest.

Is there any setting or code need to add on win10 project for receiving push notification?
Can win10 universal app use windows push notification service currently?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but they might've changed xml format for Windows 10 push notifications.AFAIK iOS and Android push templates accepts only json and Windows is XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you bothering trying to handle the push notifications yourself? You should look into Amazon's SNS service. They handle the differences between devices so you don't have to. Unless you are interested in push notifications and want to take the time to learn, but if you're more interested in your core app I would say save time and use existing robust methods.

It's like writing in assembly vs using a compiler.
You're doing assembly right now.
Do you need to be that granular?

Do you want to hand code the changes required when you want to migrate to the next version or just sit back and pay a few pennies. AWS services are dirt cheap and they give a fair amount of free usage on their services you may end up paying nothing.